# Problem with atbegshi and caption / chapter

Tags: errors, captions, chapters, atbegshi

I'm trying to insert pages in a document using `\AtBeginShipoutNext` from the `atbegshi` package. However, I'm getting errors when the page where `\AtBeginShipoutNext` is called contains a `\chapter{}` or `\caption{}` command.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{This caption breaks everything}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The command

```
\AtBeginShipoutNext{
\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\box\AtBeginShipoutBox
\stepcounter{page}\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\hbox{}}
```

adds a blank page and adjusts the page counter.

The problem occurs when the above command is inserted before `\chapter{First Chapter}` or `\begin{figure}` in the MWE. I get the errors

```
! Undefined control sequence.\GenericError #4 \errhelp \@err@ l.15 \lipsum[1-4]
```

and

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 23.
```

respectively.

**EDIT:** It appears that `AtBeginShipoutNext` somehow breaks the .aux file when the current page contains references (in this case the page number of the chapter and the caption)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's unclear what `\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\box\AtBeginShipoutBox` should do. In any case you have to use `\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\hbox{}`.

Comment: `\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\box\AtBeginShipoutBox` ships out the next page as is in order to insert a page _afterwards_. Otherwise the next page would just be replaced by the blank page.

Comment: `\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\hbox{}` gives the same errors. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `atbegshi` provides hook, when the page is output. Usually, the page is output *after* the hooks are processed, which might modify the output page. Then the meaning of `\protect` is the original meaning of `\protect` before the hooks, LaTeX sets it to `\noexpand` in the output routine. Package `atbegshi` sets `\protect` to `\relax` (`\set@typeset@protect`) in order to allow the user to modify the output page contents with the usual meaning of `\protect`.

In this case, the page is already output in the hook, therefore the meaning of `\protect` should be fixed. Otherwise the write whatsits (`\contentsline`) can break.

In addition, `\AtBegShiDiscard` must be called to notify `atbegshi`, that the page is not shipped out a second time after the hooks.

Full example with an empty second page:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\AtBeginShipoutNext{%
  \begingroup
    \let\protect\noexpand
    \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\box\AtBeginShipoutBox
    \stepcounter{page}\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null
  \endgroup
  \AtBeginShipoutDiscard
}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{This caption breaks everything}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

### Package `afterpage`

The same result with package `afterpage`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{\afterpage{\shipout\null}}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{This caption breaks everything}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for the MWE. Haven't tried it in my actual document yet, but I have accepted your answer.